# Logic to check if a query set exists on a None type?

Tags: python

I'm showing my example below with 2 groups when there are over 20 groups in the code.  I'm not sure if there is a better way to go about this if there is please offer a suggestion.

Below I'm checking if the student has 'All Groups' for their student group if they do I want to the groups as None.  This part is working fine, same with the else.

```
    allgroups = 'All Groups'
# if user has all groups then no group will show
    if allgroups in studentgroup:
        bhstudentgrouplist = None
        abstudentgrouplist = None
    else:
        bhstudentgrouplist = Groups.objects.filter(~Q(group_id__in= 
        groupIds)).filter(group_id = 2000)
        abstudentgrouplist = Groups.objects.filter(~Q(group_id__in= 
        groupIds)).filter(group_id = 5000)
```

What's occuring is if user has every item possible in the group they should be flagged as None so they wont' display in my template.  In order to do this, I tried the following:

1.

```
if not bhstudentgrouplist.exists():
    bhstudentgrouplist = None
if not abstudentgrouplist.exists():
    abstudentgrouplist = None
```

2.

```
if bhstudentgrouplist.count() < 1:
    bhstudentgrouplist = None
if not abstudentgrouplist.count() < 1:
    abstudentgrouplist = None
```

3.

```
if bhstudentgrouplist.isnull():
    bhstudentgrouplist = None
if not abstudentgrouplist.isnull():
    abstudentgrouplist = None
```

This works for the instances except when a student has All Groups, I get the error can not use the function isnull(), count(), exists() on a None type.  How can I go about fixing when the group falls in All Groups and the student has already has all reports in the studentgroup so it needs to be set to None?  If there is a better way to go about this entire process please guide me in that direction.

The process is checking if a student has All Groups if they don't it will provide the list of available reports.  Sometimes the user already has all the available reports in these instances the report group should be set to none, so it doesn't return available reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than set bhstudentgrouplist to None, you should set it to an empty queryset. Then it will still have access to the queryset functions

```
 if allgroups in studentgroup:
    bhstudentgrouplist = Groups.objects.none()
    abstudentgrouplist = Groups.objects.none()
else:
    b...
```

Then queryset member functions such as `bhstudentgrouplist.count() = 0`
work, though I am not sure about isnull()

Comment: Thank you for this MagicLamp you're a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little unsure of the ultimate goal, but I can at least fix the error you're getting.  If you add a check on the variable before each if statement, like so:

```
if bhstudentgrouplist and not bhstudentgrouplist.exists():
```

That way, if one of the variables is `None`, the statement will fail before trying to call a function on it.  Depending on your exact use case, you might be able to simplify it to just checking the variable anyway:

```
if bhstudentgrounplist:
```

or

```
if not bhstudentgrouplist:
```

since an empty list will evaluate to `false`.

One more thing to consider would be to store your data in a dictionary.  Your current variable names could be the keys, and the lists could be the values. That way instead of explicitly writing each check for 20 groups, you can just loop through it.